# Can other android app see my app class names?

Tags: android

Can other applications see my class and variable names?

Comment: did you obfuscate your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can. You can prove it by for example installing one of apk decompilers (available in Play Store), then decompile an app you have installed on that phone.

You'll see the classes names as developer wrote them. Most of the times that names would be obfuscated but some apks do not use obfuscation (your apk is the case).

As in original question:

> After our app update went live, some users that were using Kaspersky antivirus app reported that our app were flagged as Trojan.
>   After some investigation and testing i found out that changing source code (class names) helped to clear the flag.

Comment: _Some APKs do not use obfuscation (your apk is the case)_, either you know OP personally, or this has been thrown out of chance.

Comment: My answer was for the ORIGINAL question where author clearly states that other application could do that and my answer says why. Do you have any meaningful thoughts to add?